# How to get Fields Name of particular Layer with LayerID with ESRI

Tags: ios, gis, arcgis

i actually tried ways , even checked ESRI sample code QueryTaskExample.  i need simply to get Fields Names or Attributes of any Layer .

i used following method...

```
self.queryTask = [AGSQueryTask queryTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strMAPURL]]; // here i send like @"http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3"


        self.queryTask.delegate = self;

        //return all fields in query
        self.query = [AGSQuery query];
        self.query.outFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"*", nil];

        self.query.text = @"Fields";
        [self.queryTask executeWithQuery:self.query];


i access below delegates :

//results are returned
- (void)queryTask:(AGSQueryTask *)queryTask operation:(NSOperation *)op didExecuteWithFeatureSetResult:(AGSFeatureSet *)featureSet {
  //get feature, and load in to table
  self.featureSet = featureSet; 
  [super.tableView reloadData];
}
```

featureSet.fields  // this should be giving me Name of Fields for Layer 3....

but i am getting Array as 0 elements......  i need to get Fields in same order as there in Server Layer.